# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular App that uses Froala Editor and i currently use the Ignite Overlay component to show dialogs to the User to provide initial Data. As i am running into more and more issues regarding Ignite Components working with others i am trying to move as much as posible to Angular Material. In this case i am trying to replace a Oberlay popup with an Mat Dialog, but i am not having much luck. When i call dialog.open i get the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')

the code i am trying to register is

Below is the function i am trying to register.

```
   initUploadEvents(): Object {
        const _froalaUploadService = this;
        return {
            'image.beforeUpload': function (images) {
                // make copies of the data passed in since they are lost after false is returned to froala from this callback
                const copies = {
                    editor: this,  // {...editor}, // make full copy of editor object
                    // e: {...e}, // make full copy of the event
                    images: {...images}, // make full copy of the images
                };

                let imageBase64 = null;

                // create reader
                if (images.length) {
                    // Create a File Reader.
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    // Set the reader to insert images when they are loaded.
                    reader.onload = (ev) => {
                        imageBase64 = ev.target['result'];
                        // console.log('file reader result ', imageBase64);
                    };
                    // Read image as base64.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(images[0]);
                }

                _froalaUploadService.editorInstance = this;

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalImagePropertiesComponent,
        {
            data: '',
            disableClose: false, width: '600px', position: {
                top: '50px'
            },
        })
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('We git an unsubscribe')
    });
}


                
        // Old Code        const overlayId = _froalaUploadService.overlayService.show(ModalImagePropertiesComponent);

                _froalaUploadService.overlayService.onOpened.pipe(
                    takeWhile(_ => _froalaUploadService.alive),
                    // filter(event => !!(event.componentRef && event.componentRef.instance)),
                    switchMap(($overlayEvent: OverlayEventArgs) => {
                        // console.log('event ', copies.e, ' editor ', copies.editor, ' images ', copies.images);
                        // @ts-ignore
                        const modalInstance = <ModalImagePropertiesComponent>$overlayEvent.componentRef.instance;
                        // Splitting the name (filename) here and taking the first part which represents the name without the extension
                        modalInstance.imageProperties = {
                            filename: copies.images[0].name.split('.')[0],
                            original_filename: copies.images[0].name,
                            myFile: imageBase64,
                            user_id: _froalaUploadService.userId,
                        };
                        return modalInstance.onDismiss;
                    }),
                    take(1), // this makes sure the subscription stays alive for only one instance
                )
                    .subscribe((modalResult: IUploadedImageProperties | boolean) => {
                        if (typeof modalResult === 'boolean') {
                            // just dismiss the dialog, user didn't fill the form
                            _froalaUploadService.overlayService.hide(overlayId);
                        } else {
                            console.log(modalResult, this.image.get());
                            // Insert image into editor.
                            this.image.insert(`${modalResult.link}`, false, null, copies.editor.image.get(), modalResult);
                            _froalaUploadService.overlayService.hide(overlayId);
                        }
                    });


                // editor.options.imageUploadParams[csrf_token_name]=csrf_token_value;
                /*if (images.length) {
                    // Create a File Reader.
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    // Set the reader to insert images when they are loaded.
                    reader.onload = (ev) => {
                        const result = ev.target['result'];
                        editor.image.insert(result, null, null, editor.image.get());
                        console.log(ev, editor.image, ev.target['result'])
                    };
                    // Read image as base64.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(images[0]);
                }*/
                // Return false if you want to stop the image upload.
                return false;
            },
            'image.uploaded': function (response) {
                // Parse response to get image url.
                console.log(response)
                const img_url = JSON.parse(response).link;

                // Insert image.
                // editor.image.insert(`${_froalaUploadService.loadImageUrl}${img_url}`, false, null, editor.image.get(), response);

                return false;
            },
            'froalaEditor.image.inserted': function (e, editor, $img, response) {
                // _that.editorInstance = editor;
                // Image was inserted in the editor.
            },
            'froalaEditor.image.replaced': function (e, editor, $img, response) {
                // _that.editorInstance = editor;
                // Image was replaced in the editor.
            },
            'froalaEditor.image.error': function (e, editor, error, response) {
                // Bad link.
                if (error.code === 1) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 2) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 3) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 4) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 5) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 6) {
                    //
                } else if (error.code === 7) {
                    //
                }

                // Response contains the original server response to the request if available.
            },
        };
    }
```

Comment: Where is `this.dialog` defined and where does `initUploadEvents() ` get called? A bit more context wold be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Basically your function creates different `this` so it doesn't have access to the `this.dialog` from the DI in the constructor. Either call your function using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), use an arrow function or pass the `dialog` to as param to your function.

Comment: How can i pass the dialog to the to the function as i have no way of changing how the function is called as its a 3 party component

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I changed my event to an arrow function and it worked!!